# Don't show DateTime format on a web part

Tags: list, gridview

I Created a WebPart with a GridView.I get items of list and show in gridview.

Run-time ,datetime field displays only the time.

```
list.GetItems().GetDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) property on your date BoundField:

```
boundField.DataFormatString = "{0:d}";
```

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235324/datetime-format-in-asp-net-gridview) was asked on Stackoverflow.